# Jquery function is not firing

Tags: jquery, click

Im in basic learning of JQuery, having problem with a simple code.

When I click #needle, it supposed to toggle #leftmenu. But #needle's click function is not firing at all. Even tried some other elements click function (such as img/ button..etc.) instead of #needle div, but didn't work neither.

here is Masterpage:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/js_default.js"></script>
     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="pageContent">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="top">
               //..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content"> 
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
           //..           
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <div id="container">
           <div id="leftmenu">
             //some menu..       
           </div>
           <div id="needle">
               //..
           </div>
       <div id="stid">
            //..           
       </div>
       <div id="stin">
         //..
       </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#needle").click(function () {
        $("#leftmenu").toggle();
    });   
});
```

Comment: Please add jsfiddle so we can revise your code

Comment: can you reproduce problem in fiddle?

Comment: and is the html coming after page load dynamically? if yes then use delegated event

Comment: Works fine: [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1x6ayspg/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/80qz4nrq/ . It Works fine here. But not working in mine. I use asp.Net Masterpage may be that causes @EhsanSajjad

Comment: @linda if you show us actual code in the OP then we can say something after seeing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while i asked this question but i found the problem:

I use folders to organize aspx pages. Having subfolders is good to organize, but there are some issues with it, because JQuery does not work for pages which are in seperate folders.

So, in asp.net I should describe script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Js/file.js") %>'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Works Fine [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L97ax44j/)

may be two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling `$.noConflict( true )` from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version. [More INFO](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: I use masterpage and load tis statement in there : <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: change this script to `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>` that I used. if your problem not solved. leave the online url of your code? I'll check it

Comment: didnt work, i have updated my question with more details

Comment: do you have checked your page with firebug ? did you get any error message on document ready ?